# if link clicked beautifulsoup (python) event

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to do something if someone click a link? I need to know when someone clicking at that link because if so, I want to execute some code.

```
a = soup.find('a') #there is only one link in the page
```

So in pseudocode I need something like this:

```
if a.clicked() == "true":
    print "link clicked"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, clicking is an event in a web browser, not something that happens in the HTML structure for a page.

When you use BeautifulSoup, you load the same HTML a browser loads, but there is nothing connecting that HTML structure to what is loaded into some random user's browser, which handles the link clicking.

Comment: Can I do something different? because in the original html there is a link that taking you somewhere and I want in my html when someone click that link to load the another site and print the new html

Comment: @Loclip: Not sure what you want to do. *There is no click event*. Just load the link yourself.